# Visual Studio two unit test files, only one executes

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a unit two unit test files in Visual Studio 2012. When I build the project and go to the Test Explorer, I only have the unit tests from the first test file. Both test files classes have the same namespaces included and the classes are decorated with the [TestClass] attribute, the methods with [TestMethod] attribute.

What do I need to do to include the second text class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make it public?
Did you clean and build the solution?
Try Exit and re enter the VS2012.

It happend to me too and the above actions solved it

Comment: OK, didn't know that it has to be a public class. Thx!